# Creating directories using __init__.py

Tags: python, directory

I am trying to learn how to use directories and folders in my code. I tried following this tutorial:  https://timothybramlett.com/How_to_create_a_Python_Package_with___init__py.html and then adding on to it.
I have tried to create a minimum reproducible code.
The folder structure looks like this:

```
main_folder
├── folder1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── file1.py
│   ├── file1_1.py
├── folder2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── file2.py
├── __init__.py
example1.py
```

The last **init**.py looks like this (the other ones inside the folders are empty):

```
from .folder1.file1_1 import *
from .folder1.file1 import function1
from .folder2.file2 import function2
```

The idea is that file1 takes in some values from file1_1. file2 calculates some numbers, and both file1 and file 2 is used in the example1 file.

file1_1:

```
nr = 5
```

The code in file 1 is:

```
 from .file1_1 import *


#test that uses the back_function to compute and return in function1
def back_function1(a):
    b = nr + a # a+5
    return b


def function1(a):
    number = back_function1(a)+2 # a + 5 + 2
    print("hello function 1")
    return number
```

The code in file 2 is:

```
def function2():
    print("hello function 2")
```

In example1 it is this:

```
import main_folder as m

m.function1(2)
m.function2()
```

The problem is that when I run example1.py the whole system runs. However, if I try to run only file1 I get the following error:

```
    from .file1_1 import *
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

But if I change the `from .file1_1 import *` to `from file1_1 import *`, then the opposite happens (I can run file1.py but not example1.py).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run a submodule you can use the -m flag:

`python -m package.subpackage1.moduleX`

In your case:

`python -m main_folder.folder1.file1`

Look at this question for a detailed explanation:

[Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time/14132912#14132912)

If you really want to just be able to change the script to make it work change your import statement in file 1 to:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from file1_1 import *
else:
    from .file1_1 import *
```

It will work but it is not how you would usually structure your python code.

Comment: I tried running that line of code from the terminal, however I get the following warning: RuntimeWarning: 'main_folder.folder1.file1' found in sys.modules after import of package 'main_folder.folder1', but prior to execution of 'main_folder.folder1.file1'; this may result 
in unpredictable behaviour
  warn(RuntimeWarning(msg)). 

Additionally, I don't understand what I can write in the script (not in the terminal) to make it work? I am sorry I am a bit dense

Comment: @IdaSB I have added a way to do what you want to do but I still recommend you to read the answer I linked earlier.